# How to create a custom ul element with polymer dart which fires on-added and on-remove event when children are added?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have been making a simple todo list as a way to learn polymer dart.
[Here is my todo example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639961/why-does-hosthover-not-work-here%22todo%20example%22).
I have limited experience in web-programming in general. My idea is to create a simple app with

- One text input
- 2 Custom ul elements (New task ul and Done task ul)
- Entering a string in text input and pressing enter creates a li item which is added to New task.
- Deleting an element from New task results in addition of element to Done task.
- Now I know creating a separate model and tracking the changes in an observable list seperate from html might be better approach. But as a learning exercise I would like to create a custom ul which fires a on-added and on-removed event when li item are added and removed from it respectively.

Now I have a couple of questions.

1. Why is there no on-added or on-remove event in ul (html)? I would like to understand what is the rational behind it.
2. How would one go about creating a custom UListElement which fires on-added and on-removed event when li items are added or removed from it respectively?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because normally you won't need it. As you wrote you change the model and let Polymer update the view.
2. You can easily implement it yourself by overriding the `attached`/`detached` methods and fire an event.
   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22424213/217408 for how to fire custom events in Polymer.dart.

Answer (score 1):

Gunter is right. You're thinking is a little old school, so I'm surprised to hear that you're new to web dev. With Polymer, you need to embrace the data-driven view model. You want to be watching the backing model properties that are driving your view, not the DOM. Something like this:

`@observable List<Task> tasks;`

`void tasksChanged(oldValue) {
  // react to changes
}`